# How to add UILabel above UILabel

Tags: ios, uilabel

If i set `bottomLabel`.text = Chinese character,i can't see the `aboveLabel` when i run it and if i debug view hierarchy i can see it.so what's the problem?

```
    UILabel *bottomLabel  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 40)];
    bottomLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    bottomLabel.text = @"中文";
    [self.view addSubview:bottomLabel];   
    UILabel *aboveLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)];
    aboveLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    aboveLabel.text = @"aboveLabel";
    [bottomLabel addSubview:aboveLabel];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are adding aboveLabel as subview of bottomLabel hence it doesnot get displayed when you assign chinese character to it. You can see it view hierarchy as it is assigned a frame and added as subview. If you want to add one UILabel above UILabel you can add both labels as subview of common parent view. 
i.e.

```
[self.view addSubview:bottomLabel]; 
[self.view addSubview:aboveLabel];
```

Answer (score 3):

[image]

why dont you use `NSMutableAttributedString` for this with one LABEL.

```
NSString *text1 = @"Hello";
NSString *date1 = @"                                               12.05 Pm\n";

NSString *text2 = @"World";
NSString *date2 = @"                                               11.00 AM";


self.lbl.numberOfLines = 0;

NSString * str = [text1 stringByAppendingString:date1];
NSString * str2 = [text2 stringByAppendingString:date2];



UIFont *text1Font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:10];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: str attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : text1Font }];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle1 = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle1 setAlignment: NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[paragraphStyle1 setLineSpacing:1];
[attributedString1 addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value: paragraphStyle1 range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString1 length])];


UIFont *text2Font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:10];
NSMutableAttributedString *attributedString2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString: str2 attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName : text2Font }];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle2 = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
[paragraphStyle2 setLineSpacing:1];
[paragraphStyle2 setAlignment: NSTextAlignmentLeft];
[attributedString2 addAttribute:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName value: paragraphStyle2 range:NSMakeRange(0, [attributedString2 length])];

   [attributedString1 appendAttributedString:attributedString2];

   [self.lbl setAttributedText:attributedString1];
```

Comment: because i'm trying to display time of the content,time should always be located at the last line of content and maybe it will overlap the content.

Comment: I have Updated Code Check its Working

Answer (score 1):

[image]

because above label is overlap on  bottom label like above image so you not display that if you see that label above label x position change then it display.

if x value set 50 then you display bottm label.

Comment: if i set bottomLabel.text = @"abc" it works well, and i am not very sure what you said, can you explain it more?

Comment: Your above label is ovelap on bottom label so bottom text not display.

Comment: set bottomLabel.text = @"abc",then run,you will see these two labels.my question is  why if i set bottomLabel.text = @"中文",i can't see the green label?

Comment: your above label frame x position change and set 50 then display bottom and above label.

Comment: I think the difference is label's text `bottomLabel.text = @"中文"`,`bottomLabel.text = @"abc"`,It will be great if you can show me your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to adding `aboveLabel` inside of `bottomLabel`.Instead add both into one view or self.view.

Answer (score 0):

```
UILabel *bottomLabel  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, 200, 40)];
    bottomLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    bottomLabel.text = @"中文";
    [self.view addSubview:bottomLabel];
    UILabel *aboveLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(bottomLabel.frame)+10, 60, 30)];
    aboveLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    aboveLabel.text = @"aboveLabel";
    [self.view addSubview:aboveLabel];
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this code**

**Objective - C**

```
    UILabel *bottomLabel  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 30)];
    bottomLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    bottomLabel.text = @"中文";
    [self.view addSubview:bottomLabel];   
    UILabel *aboveLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(50, 0, 60, 30)];
    aboveLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    aboveLabel.text = @"abc";
    [bottomLabel addSubview:aboveLabel];
```

Comment: I can't see the  aboveLabel. Test on Xcode 8.3.2 iOS 10.3 both simulator and iPhone.

Comment: put your output screenshot.

Comment: copy -> paste -> run